# How to remove completely the php packages from ondrej PPA?

Tags: apt, ppa, php

I have Ubuntu 14.04, wanted to try php5.6.

Added `ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6`. Updated. Installed php5. Got php5.6. Did not find some extensions and decided to switch back to ubuntu's own php 5.5.

Deleted that ppa. Updated. Uninstalled php5. Installed php5.
`apt-get` says it is installing php5.5 but after that `php -v` says php5.6.
Tried almost the same in different combinations several times with `clean`, `purge`, `remove`, `autoremove` etc. No result.

Even deleted `/usr/bin/php` to make sure it is restored upon installation. But it is not.

not only I cannot delete `php5.6` but `apache2` as well. and now it messed up with my `nginx`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can PPAs be removed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed) add back the PPA, then use `ppa-purge`.

Comment: that question helps but not a duplicate as motivation is completely different. have to accept my own answer because I don't know how to accept comment as the right answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Used `ppa-purge ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6` as suggested by **muru**.
It helped. Had to fix all configs manually though.